Fibers of $t\mapsto t^n$ on $\operatorname{Spec}k[t^{\pm1}]$
Let's say $k$ is algebraically closed and $n$ is prime to the characteristic. Consider the multiplication-by-$n$ map $f:k[t^{\pm1}]\longrightarrow k[t^{\pm1}]$ given by $t\mapsto t^n$. I find myself quite confused by the induced map on schemes. In particular, I'm trying to see where the prime $(t-1)$ goes i.e., what maps to $(t-1)$ under $f$ i.e., what is $f^{-1}(t-1)$. Is it right to say that $(t-1)\subset f^{-1}(t-1)$ because $(t^n-1)\subset (t-1)$? By extension is it correct to say that the fiber above $(t-1)$ contains $(t-\zeta_n^k)$ for $0\leq k<n$? Now then I suppose I should ask what prime contains all of those? But they're all maximal! So I'm certainly very lost and I suspect there's a simple thing I just can't see yet. Thanks!

Note that if $n=2$, then $t+1\mapsto t^2+1 \notin (t-1)$.
Your inclusion
$$(t-1)\subset f^{-1}(t-1)$$
is correct, and since $(t-1)$ is a maximal ideal, this is actually an equality. This means that the map on schemes maps the point $t=1$ to itself.
Now if you want to determine the fiber you have to ask for all prime with that property. And indeed, those correspond to the $n$-th roots of unity.
